Создание базы данных через Visual Studio
Как исправить ошибку, которую выдаёт Visual Studio 2022 при создании базы данных?
Мне нужно создать базу данных в Visual Studio, вот ошибка, которую я получаю.


Пкм по проекту -> Управление пакетами NuGet... -> Вкладка "Обзор", под ней поле для поиска туда пишешь microsoft.data.sqlclient, нажимаешь поиск, первое из списка будет эта библиотека, на ее нажимаешь и откроет подробности и тд. там и кнопка установки.
